# Finding out the type of a set

Tags: java, generics, set

Given a `Set<X>`, I want to write a method that acts differently depending on the class `X` is. In actuality, I'd have 2 cases: `A` or `B`.

The method looks like:

```
public<X> boolean myMethod(Set<X> mySet)
{
 // if X is actually the class A
 ...
 // if X is B
 ...
}
```

I am not sure how to check this. I tried `X::getClass`, but it wouldn't let me use `equals` method.

Comment: @f1sh Not really

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have anything in common? Do they extend the same upper class or implement the same interface?

Comment: @Eritrean They don't extend the same upper class or so. Simply 2 possible class types.

Comment: Due to type erasure you cannot get the class of `X`. If you could add `Class<X> entryClass` as a parameter you can use this in your `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take one object from set and check class of single object
like below, please check

```
public<X> boolean myMethod(Set<X> mySet)
{
    Object tmpObj = null;
    
    for(Object obj : set){
        tmpObj = obj;
        break;
    }
    if(tmpObj instanceof A){
        // if X is actually the class A
    }else if(tmpObj instanceof B){
        // // if X is B
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `mySet` is empty?

Comment: in this case you need to add extra check and this code will not work.

Answer (score 2):

### In a general sense, this is not possible

Due to type erasure, a Java `Set` *does not have a generic type* at runtime.  Generics act as compile-time checks on the objects passed into methods, but consequently the specific values are not available at runtime.  A `Set<String>` is the same class as a `Set<Map<Integer, Thread>>` and the same class as a bare `Set`.

#### Potential workaround with class parameter

If you really need to know this, you could change the signature of your method to be:

```
public <X> boolean myMethod(Set<X> mySet, Class<X> clazz)
```

Now you have a `Class` instance available at runtime, which is guaranteed to be compatible with `X`.  This you can introspect (e.g. `String.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)`).

There are two drawbacks to this approach: firstly, you'll have to explicitly pass in the extra parameter each time the method is called.  Secondly, if `A` and `B` can be subclasses of one another, this is not going to work; you could pass in e.g. `B.class` even when the generic parameter was `A`.

### However, this feels like a code smell

You shouldn't be trying to do fundamentally different things based on a generic parameter.  Instead of switching behaviour in your method here, *do something different within the classes A and B*:

```
public<X> boolean myMethod(Set<X> mySet)
{
   boolean result = false;
   for (X x : mySet) {
      result &= x.doSomething();
   }

   return result;
}

class A implements MyDoSomethingInterface {
    public boolean doSomething() {
        // Here you put the logic for "if X is A"
    }
}

class B implements MyDoSomethingInterface {
    public boolean doSomething() {
        // Here you put the logic for "if X is B"
    }
}
```

And if your reaction is that this won't work because A and B are built-in classes, you'll need to wrap them in your own domain objects (which is the correct approach anyway because you want to associate this extra behaviour with them).